# Booting problem

Tags: dual-boot, boot-repair

I got dual boot on my laptop recently which was only with windows 10 before,but now after I got back my laptop the booting speed of Ubuntu 20.04LTS is 2 mins and above,can someone please help me with this.i am new to Linux and have no idea about anything, I'd appreciate if anyone can guide me step by step of the process of fixing this .
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please read https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask Your question is not answerable in this state. Please [edit] and add details. Also you can try to google about "ubuntu slow boot".

Comment: but now after I got back my laptop the booting speed of Ubuntu 20.04LTS is 2 mins and above   got back from where?